# nvidia drivers on 20.04 headless server

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, 20.04, headless

I'm installing Nvidia driver 450 on a 20.04 brand new server with **no** desktop environment (which I do not want to have).

(*Context*: final goal is to install cuda toolkit via Tensorflow Docker, and drivers are the only thing outta container).

When it comes to `apt` install, turns out that both `nvidia-driver-450`/`nvidia-driver-450-server` packages will carry a huge load of gnome-related stuff.

So I'm wondering if `nvidia-headless-450`/`nvidia-headless-450-server` will suffice. Asking for both brokes apt, so my questions are

1. what's the `-server` suffixed variant supposed to do? [Official guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions) doesn't clarify much.
2. is the headless metapackage containing the actual driver?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262401/what-is-the-nvidia-server-driver/1267511#1267511  The answer uses apt-file list to check contents of packages not installed on system.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this](https://denishartl.com/installing-cuda-11-3-cudnn-tensorflow-2-4-jupyter-on-a-headless-ubuntu-20-04-server/) method. It does not use docker, it is manual apt. Also there are headless nvidia drivers for exactly this purpose.