# What is the difference between nvidia-driver-* and nvidia-dirver-*-server?

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-mate

I have default Ubuntu repositories and get to install proprietary video drivers. I opened the "Software & Updates" section in the Settings and...
What is the difference between NVidia driver with -server suffix and without one. Which a meta-package should I install?

[image: Additional Drivers tab]

Both the options, nvidia-driver-470 and nvidia-driver-470-server, have a similar description that does not clarify which one should I prefer. Maybe I should install both of them? But Software Properties offer radio buttons only.

```
Description: NVIDIA driver metapackage
 This metapackage depends on the NVIDIA binary driver and on all of its libraries,
 to provide hardware acceleration for OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES/Vulkan
 applications on either X11 or on Wayland.
 .
 See /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-470/README.txt.gz
 for a complete list of supported GPUs and PCI IDs.
```

Comment: No, you should always install the "tested" one.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262401/what-is-the-nvidia-server-driver