# What is the difference between drivers nvidia server drivers and just nvidia, and why can't I change the resolution when I install just nvidia?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, additional-drivers

What is the difference between NVIDIA server drivers and just NVIDIA drivers, and why can't I change the screen resolution when I install just NVIDIA drivers?

Additional Drivers:

[image]
<sub>**This device is using an alternative driver.**</sub>
<sup>**Using NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-510-server (proprietary)**</sup>

and also why when installing the NVIDIA driver without the "server",  does it write in the "graphics" item llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits) in my system description?

Comment: Based solely on my experience, `nvidia-drive-470` has been pretty stable for me. I'm using Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1417494/570833

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the results of `apt show nvidia-driver-510-server`:

```
Description: NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage
 This metapackage depends on the NVIDIA binary driver and on all of its libraries,
 to provide hardware acceleration for OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES/Vulkan
 applications on either X11 or on Wayland.
```

This package provides the basic functionality needed to provide hardware acceleration for OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES/Vulkan applications on either X11 or on Wayland, however it may not be the optimal package for compatibility with your NVIDIA graphics card. In order to install the most compatible proprietary graphics drivers let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install.

Remove the currently installed NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot
```

Let the ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The install option of ubuntu-drivers installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies. The graphics driver packages that are installed by these commands will receive software updates in the same way as other apt packages are updated.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!