# Problem with latest Nvidia 525 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've installed the Nvidia driver version 525, recommended by my terminal with the command 'ubuntu-drivers devices' and with the app 'Software & Updates', but after reboot, I'm left with nothing but a black screen. I've tried to access the login screen with Ctrl + Alt + F6, and it works but not after telling me that my GPU isn't properly recognized.

Tried it on Ubuntu 22.04 with Linux kernel 5.0.19.35 & 5.0.19.32 but it doesn't work on either. It also seems to have permanently bricked the 5.0.19.35 version, because now it only shows a blinking underscore when I try to boot it up, even after purging all the Nvidia drivers with 'sudo apt-get purge nvidia*'.

I just wanted to confirm if this is confirmed to be an issue with the Nvidia drivers or not, and if it isn't a common problem, what could be a good fix for this.

'ubuntu-drivers devices' output:

```
ignacio@ignacio-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F95sv000017AAsd00003A44bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

'nvidia-smi' output:

```
ignacio@ignacio-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~$ nvidia-smi
No se ha encontrado la orden «nvidia-smi», pero se puede instalar con:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510-server  # version 510.47.03-0ubuntu3, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version    390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.216.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.161.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510         # version 510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515         # version 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515-server  # version 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525         # version 525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525-server  # version 525.85.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

This is the output of the attempt made in the kernel version 5.19.0.32, not the problematic version .35 - As you can see, all the Nvidia drivers were purged, but after installing them again, I get the black screen again, this time on the kernel v. 5.19.0.32

Comment: Did you try the recovery/safe mode under the grub advanced menu item?  If you used the 525-open driver, I'd try the driver without the "open".

Comment: @ubfan1 I actually only used recovery mode to purge the drivers to be able to boot normally. Only managed to get 5.19.0.32 running though, .35 doesn’t even get past a black screen with an unresponsive underscore at the top left of the screen

Comment: To aid your investigations, when you get the black screen and cursor, does ctrl+alt+F4 give you a login prompt? If so, try logging in, then you can investigate the system. Alternatively, you could install openssh-server and log in from another machine with ssh. I'd suggest you remove sshd after you're done unless you have a need for it.

Comment: @RussellJones I’ve tried it on 5.19.0.35, but nothing takes the unresponsive blinking underscore away, I don’t even get to see the cursor, I’m thinking of just reinstalling the kernel version and starting again from scratch

Comment: Try this: Assuming a desktop with HDMI connection, shut down the computer, then plug the screen into the on board graphics port. Restart and it should now work and you will be able to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @Raffles I messed up by no mentioning I’m using a notebook, Lenovo Gaming 3 15ARH05. Currently I’m booting into a older kernel version to troubleshoot, I purged all nvidia drivers in both kernel version but to no avail, still a black screen.

Comment: Please type `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` in a terminal and edit the results into your question. Edit: `nvidia-smi` as well.

Comment: @Raffles added the requested information. If I install the recommended driver in the kernel that does work, I get the black screen all over again. I was thinking perhaps installing the drivers on the problematic kernel version (.35) through recovery mode, and seeing what I get out of there.

Comment: The "recommended" is the "...525-open" driver, try the driver without the "-open".

Comment: Please see if this helps, after purging the nvidia drivers, use `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall   
sudo reboot  `
the full answer is here >>> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416220/what-is-the-difference-between-drivers-nvidia-server-drivers-and-just-nvidia-an

Comment: @IgnacioThomson Use `sudo fwupdmgr get-updates` to check if you have the latest firmware.