# How to install nvidia driver for cuda without installing X11 on ubuntu server?

Tags: server, nvidia, xorg, cuda

I am using the ubuntu server 20.04LTS Operating system.

I looking to install Nvidia drivers on my server. I need to install it without a headless because I don’t want to use GUI.

I don’t want to Install X11.

How to do this Please help with this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1417494/15811

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the NVIDIA Server Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262401/what-is-the-nvidia-server-driver)